# ItemsControl StatusChanged equivalent in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, rendering

We were able to understand if ItemsControl finished it's rendering by checking Status within StatusChanged event in WPF.

How can I make sure that ItemsControl finished rendering in UWP? I want to make sure that rendering is completed and access some elements using ContainerFromItem.

Comment: What did you want to do by using 'ContainerFromItem'?

Comment: I have custom dragging logic using events like ManipulationDelta. 

After rendering, I want to get the ContentPresenter's position based on it's parent UIElement and then use that position to draw some stuff using Win2D.

I need item's position, so I need the container, so I need to make sure containers are rendered in the first place, and it goes like that.

Answer (score 0):

> I have custom dragging logic using events like ManipulationDelta. After rendering, I want to get the ContentPresenter's position based on it's parent UIElement and then use that position to draw some stuff using Win2D. I need item's position, so I need the container, so I need to make sure containers are rendered in the first place, and it goes like that.

To use ItemsControl in UWP, you also need to know about the [UI virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-gridview-and-listview#ui-virtualization). The ItemsControl uses UI virtualization. It means that not all items will be rendered at the same time, instead only the viewable area.

You could try the following code:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="item">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I registered the `Loaded` event for the 'Grid' which is included in every item.